# AdMob freezing my Windows Phone application

Tags: windows-phone-7, admob

I'm trying AdMob control for Windows Phone 7. 
When my application starts, everything freezes until AdMob gets an ad.
Of course this is super annoying and a blocker bug for me. It seems it is doing a synchronous call using the UI thread. Is that the case?
Is there a way to avoid this?

UPDATE: Many months later and still the same problem. The funny thing is that if you try to complain in admob forum, your post is automatically deleted.

Shame on you, Google...

Comment: Creating a splash page which let users to wait few seconds until admob gets an ad? Admob control does not only freeze app but also crashes app somethimes.

Comment: Not an option, because admob will get an ad from time to time. God, I can't imagine why google made such a crap control.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try http://wp7adrotator.codeplex.com/ if you want to go for ads from admob. Cause Admob provides a bad fill rate in Windows Phones and you might want to use other accounts too i.e. Microsoft Advertising SDK. Plus this solves all unresolved admob control issues too.

If you want to dig in more you might want to look at this blog post:
http://briankassay.com/blog/?p=169

You can also look for Nokia Ad Exchange too.

I hope this would help you. I used Adroator on my The Bro Code App on Windows Phone store from NerdCats

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use the native Microsoft Advertising SDK control? It works perfectly on Windows Phones.